# convert white space to tab on first line of a tab delimited file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have multiple tab delimited files with the same column headers. However, the headers (1st row of the files) are delimited by white spaces instead of tabs. How can I convert the white space to tab on first line of a tab delimited file?

Comment: Are you familiar with `unexpand` (and it's companion `expand`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` for one line only:

```
sed -i.bak $'1s/ /\t/g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use awk:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR == 1 { $1 = $1 } 1' file
```

Assigning the first field of the first line `$1` to itself causes awk to reformat the line, inserting the output field separator `OFS` (defined as a tab character). `1` is the shortest *true* condition, so awk does the default: `{ print }` for every line.

To overwrite "in-place", use a temp file:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR == 1 { $1 = $1 } 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Note that this will interpret any number of spaces as a single field separator.